# Condition on the first morphism of a ses to make Hom right exact

Tags: commutative-algebra, exact-sequence, abelian-categories

Let
$$
0 \longrightarrow M_1 \overset{\phi_1}\longrightarrow M_2 \longrightarrow M_3 \longrightarrow 0
$$
be a short exact sequence of $R$-modules (we assume $R$ commutative). What are the conditions (if any) on $\phi_1$ which are sufficient to conclude
$$
0 \longrightarrow \mathrm{Hom}(M_3, N) \longrightarrow \mathrm{Hom}(M_2, N) \overset{\phi_1^*}\longrightarrow \mathrm{Hom}(M_1,N) \longrightarrow 0
$$
is a short exact sequence as well? In particular, when is $\phi_1^*$ surjective?

My educated guess is that it holds when $\phi_1$ is left-invertible, i.e. when the original sequence is split exact. In fact, in this case $M_2 \cong M_1 \oplus M_2/\phi_1(M_1)$, hence any $f : M_2 \to N$ can be 'split', by UP of direct sum, into $f_1 : M_1 \to N$ and $f_2 : M_2/\phi_1(M_1) \to N$. Then clearly any $f_1 \in \mathrm{Hom}(M_1,N)$ can be chosen to make $f$, and $\phi_1^* f = f_1$ is surjective.

Comment: That's certainly a sufficient condition, but it is not necessary. $\text{Hom}(-,N)$ is left exact, so you need to show that the dual map $\phi_1^*$ is surjective. That's it really.

Comment: In the sequence you want to conclude, what is $N$? If you want it for any $N$, then the original sequence must split, but there are many $N$'s for which the conclusion might be true even if the original sequence did not split. (For example, consider $N=0$.)

Comment: @Brogan that is clear. That's also what I wrote

Comment: @Mohan there are no assumptioms on $N$, and the point of the question is to not focus on that but on $\phi_1$. I now realize the sequence I wrote has to be split is just the original sequence